# Customize Xamarin Facebook iOS SDK Component LoginButton

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to customize the appearance of `LoginButton` from Xamarin Facebook iOS SDK like this:

```cs
LoginButton loginButton = new LoginButton (new CGRect (48, 0, 218, 46)) {
    LoginBehavior = LoginBehavior.Native,
    ReadPermissions = readPermissions.ToArray (),
};
loginButton.SetTitle("Test", UIControlState.Normal);
```

But nothing happens, it still has title: "Log in with Facebook". Same situation for color, font etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least changing the text (value, font and color) is easy:

```cs
var loginButton = new LoginButton(new CGRect(48, 0, 218, 46));
var attributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.Blue,
    Font = UIFont.FromName("Courier", 18f)
};
var titleText = new NSAttributedString("Your new button title", attributes);
loginButton.SetAttributedTitle(titleText, UIControlState.Normal);
```

And I just figured out the background can be removed with

```cs
loginButton.SetBackgroundImage(null, UIControlState.Normal);
```

So this might be a good starting point.